# Sending Signing Request Envelope with template and PDF Document

Tags: docusignapi

In my application I have a requirement where I need to send envelope for multiple documents. I have partially achieved this by using Composite templates. But having issues in scenario described below.

"Envelope to contain multiple templates (using Composite templates) and also PDF document with meta data(along with pdf bytes)."

I am able to achieve sending envelope with my document pdf bytes and meta data, but could not combine this along with templates in same envelope.

Can you suggest a way forward?

UPDATE: I have progressed to generate the envelope for above scenario but having problem-Now problem is that, I am using anchor text to put "sign here" tab in this pdf document and unfortunately anchor text is also present in other templates too. This is resulting in two sign here tabs on templates(These are proper templates and are not empty) with anchor text.

Adding JSON string for more visibility. Please note that I am sending PDF bytes along with this json string which is acting as backing document for empty template.

```
{
"status": "sent",
"templateId": "Empty Template ID(This template does not contain anything and just a blank pdf page in background)****************",
"templateRoles": [{
    "name": "****************",
    "accessCode": "1234",
    "roleName": "employee",
    "email": "****************",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [{
            "name": "Hyperlink Here",
            "documentId": "1",
            "anchorString": "Employee Signature:",
            "anchorXOffset": "185",
            "anchorYOffset": "-39",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "font": "arial",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "fontColor": "brightblue",
            "value": ": Click Here",
            "tabLabel": "#HREF termsAndConditionLink"
        }],
        "dateSignedTabs": [{
            "name": "DateSigned",
            "tabLabel": "DateSigned",
            "documentId": "1",
            "additionalProperties": {

            },
            "anchorString": "Employee Signature:",
            "anchorXOffset": "430",
            "anchorYOffset": "1",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels"
        }],
        "signHereTabs": [{
            "documentId": "1",
            "anchorString": "Employee Signature:",
            "anchorXOffset": "180",
            "anchorYOffset": "10",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "scaleValue": 0.0,
            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
        }]
    }
}],
"brandId": "Brand****************",
"documents": [{
    "name": "Doc2.pdf",
    "documentId": "1"
}],
"compositeTemplates": [{
    "serverTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "templateId": "Proper Template ID****************"
    }],
    "inlineTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
                "name": "****************",
                "accessCode": "1234",
                "roleName": "employee",
                "email": "****************",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [{
                        "value": "VALUE1",
                        "tabLabel": "TEXTTAB1"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "VALUE2",
                        "tabLabel": "TEXTTAB2"
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}],
"emailBlurb": "Please sign document using link below",
"emailSubject": "Please complete the documents."
```

}

Comment: Please post the JSON request body that you are sending.  Also, why aren't you able to combine with a template, do you get an error?  Please edit your answer to include these...

Comment: I managed to get it working by creating empty template and combining this empty template with rest others in composite template. I am sending pdf bytes at runtime for this empty template. Now problem is that, I am using anchor text to put "sign here" tab in this pdf document and unfortunately anchor text is also present in other templates too. This is resulting in two sign here tabs on templates with anchor text. EDITED QUESTION TO INCLUDE JSON.

Comment: @ashay thorat - Please see the answer to your anchor string issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32061388/4051306