# Docusign Anchor tab

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send a document for signing via the DocuSign REST API. I'm using Sign Here tabs with an Anchor text string.

The JSON Object request:

```
 "emailSubject" : "This is email subject",
  "emailBlurb" : "This is email body",
  "recipients" : {
    "signers" : [ {
      "routingOrder" : "1",
      "name" : "Recipeient Name",
      "email" : "Recipeient Email Address",
      "recipientId" : "1",
      "tabs" : {
        "signHereTabs" : [ {
          "anchorString" : "By:",
          "anchorXOffset" : "1",
          "anchorYOffset" : "1",
          "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : "true",
          "anchorUnits" : "inches"
        } ]
      }
    } ]
  },
  "documents" : [ {
    "name" : "document.pdf",
    "documentId" : "1",
    "bytes" : "Byte Representaton of document"
  } ],
  "status" : "sent"
}
```

This is working perfectly fine with a minor glitch: The document has two matching strings "By:", and the Sign Here tab is placed on both of them.

Is there a way I can restrict this to only add the Sign Here tab to the first instance of the string "By:" in the document?

Comment: See my answer. To add to this, you may want to consider using white text in your document (to make the anchor string invisible) and going with a naming convention gleamed from how DocuSign's Salesforce custom automatic anchors feature was designed. Documentation [link](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Using%20Anchor%20Tags.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The anchor strings on your document must be unique, otherwise that tag will be placed anywhere that string is found. See the Rules for working with anchors section [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm).

Comment: Perhaps change the document source to include the signers' designations. Eg. "By Seller:" and "By Client:"