# How to add Signer Tab at the end of the document C#

Tags: docusignapi

I am generating PDF dynamically based on the data my pdf size will change. I need to add the Signer tab at the end of the document. How to identity the end of PDF so that i can set XPosition and YPosition.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/#/definitions/signHere)

> **xPosition** : This indicates the horizontal offset of the object on the page. DocuSign uses 72 DPI when determining position. Required. May be zero.
>
> **yPosition**: This indicates the vertical offset of the object on the page. DocuSign uses 72 DPI when determining position. Required. May be zero.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request which places the signature tab on the bottom right corner.

```
{
 "emailSubject": "Please sign the agreement",
 "status": "created",
 "recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
            "name": "jane doe",
            "recipientId": 1,
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "xPosition": "560",
                        "yPosition" : "737",
                        "documentId" :"1",
                        "pageNumber" : "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
 },
 "documents": [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Agreement",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentBase64": "{{documentBase64_Pdf}}"
    }     
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of identifying end of document for placing X/Y Position, if your code is generating PDF then you can use AnchorString concept, put a white text on white label on the PDF document at the end of document. Then using DS API, put Sign Here tab over the anchor string, example is at [Docusign Anchor tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054848/docusign-anchor-tab), and details available at https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Sign%20Here%20Tab.htm and https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm